# STTwitter Library returns an error when getting tweets list for keyword with special characters

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, sttwitter

I want to get tweets list using Twitter Search API. But Recently twitter has launched New version-1.1 and it requires authorization. I'm using STTwitter library for interacting with Twitter API.

I'm using STTwitter_ios project which you can find from here :
https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/tree/master/ios

Now, I have written one sample function: fetchTweets. Authorization works successful and I'm getting the list if i search for the word (Without spaces or special characters). But When I try to search keyword with spaces or Special characters like "New york", @"New or York", etc.. then it returns error :

In the method ,
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
I'm getting error : 
{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}

```
- (void) fetchTweets {


STTwitterAPIWrapper *twitter = [STTwitterAPIWrapper twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerName:OAUTH_CONSUMER_NAME  consumerKey:OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY consumerSecret:OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET oauthToken:OAUTH_TOKEN oauthTokenSecret:OAUTH_SECRET_TOKEN];

    NSString *query = @"New york";
    NSString *searchQuery = [query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [twitter getSearchTweetsWithQuery:searchQuery successBlock:^(NSDictionary *searchMetadata, NSArray *statuses) {
        NSLog(@"Search data : %@",searchMetadata);
        NSLog(@"\n\n Status : %@",statuses);
    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
    }];
}
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: MAYBE remove the OAuth tokens / Consumer keys froms this post

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I removed OAuth token and it works fine !

See code below :

```
STTwitterAPIWrapper *twitter = [STTwitterAPIWrapper twitterAPIApplicationOnlyWithConsumerKey:OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY consumerSecret:OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET];

[twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {

    [twitter getSearchTweetsWithQuery:searchQuery successBlock:^(NSDictionary *searchMetadata, NSArray *statuses) {
        NSLog(@"Search data : %@",searchMetadata);
        NSLog(@"\n\n Status : %@",statuses);

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
    }];

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"-- error %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

I am Nicolas Seriot the creator of STTwitter.

The issue you encountered was a bug and I just [fixed it](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/commit/be15f9b746cf57e19af136326b586690f071b48d).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add HTML encode the keywords. For example with

```
 [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```